# Using BETWEEN with a subquery postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a create a query to get all attendance of the an employee within a time limit. But the time is from different table. I need to create a query like the one below, but I dont know how?

`SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE employeeid = 25 AND attendance_date BETWEEN (SELECT bill_fromdate,bill_todate FROM bill WHERE bill_id = 21487)`

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `join` instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM   attendance a 
JOIN   bill b ON 
       a.attendance_date BETWEEN b.bill_fromdate AND b.bill_todate 
WHERE  a.employeeid = 25 AND AND b.bill_id = 21487
```

Comment: A JOIN will not necessarily return the same information as the sub-query solution.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, i didnt understood what u have said.

Comment: @Mureinik there are about 30K bills and about 1000K attendance rows.So will the join create any performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

Either use a JOIN (as in Mureinik's answer) or use a sub-select with an `exists` condition:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM attendance a
WHERE a.employeeid = 25 
  AND exists (select 1 
              from bill b
              where b.bill_id = 21487 
                and a.attendance_date BETWEEN b.bill_fromdate AND b.bill_todate)
```

Given your example query, most probably there isn't a difference between using the join or the sub-select.

But they have different meanings and a join *could* return a different result (i.e. more rows) than the sub-select (but again I doubt it in this situation).